# formula generalization finit sets union

Tags: discrete-mathematics

To generalize some formula to finit sets union what is the best way to start?

let me give an example: $$n(A\cup B \cup C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) - n(A \cap B) - n(A \cap C) - n(B \cap C + n (A \cap B \cap C)  $$

How can I generalize some formula to $n$ elements, like $n(A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cdots \cup A_k)$?

Comment: Check wikipedia for inclusion-exclusion theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [Inclusion-Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), and it can be formulated as  $$ \left| \cup_{i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}} A_i \right|=\sum_{S \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}} (-1)^{|S|-1} \left| \cap_{j \in S} A_j \right|.$$  There are proofs of it at the Wikipedia site.